# Significance of light travel time in cosmology

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

When in astronomical news they say something like "It took $T$ billion years for the light from that galaxy to reach the Earth" or "The light traveled $L$ light years" what is the physical significance of $T$ or $L$?

If I understand correctly the metric of the universe can be written in the form
$$
    ds^2 = c^2 dt^2  - dl^2 = a^2(\eta) \left( d\eta^2 - d\chi^2 - R^2(\chi) d\Omega_{\theta,\phi}^2 \right)
$$
In these coordinates the matter is "at rest" ($\chi = const$) relative to the observer and the space "expands" so that the "distance" between two galaxies changes with time
$$
    r = a(\eta)\chi
$$

If at present moment $\eta = \eta_a$ I am located at $\chi=0$ and absorb a photon from the source at $\chi=\chi_s$ I know that it was emitted when $\eta_e = \eta_a-\chi_s$. At that time the "distance" to the source was
$$
    r_e = a(\eta_a - \chi_s)\chi_s
$$
Now the "distance" is
$$
    r_a = a(\eta_a)\chi_s = (1+z)r_e
$$
$z$ is redshift and can be measured. So I can understand the meaning of $z$: if they said "We found a galaxy at $z=9$" I knew it would mean that the space expanded x10 times before the light from that galaxy reached the Earth.

Taking the expantion of the space en route, the photon actually travelled the path
$$
    L = \int_{\chi_s}^0 a(\eta_a - \chi)(-d\chi)
$$
which took the time $T$:
$$
    T = t(\eta_a) - t(\eta_a-\chi_s) = L/c
$$
So neither $L$ nor $T$ have any direct meaning, they are integral quantities dependant on the model of the Universe - I have to know $a(\eta)$ and $t(\eta)$ explicitly to extract any information from $L$ or $T$.

Only for "close" sources, if $\chi_s \ll \eta_a$, I can do Taylor expansion to get
$$
    T = \frac{r_e}{c} + \frac{1}{2} H_a \left(\frac{r_e}{c}\right)^2 + ...
$$
where $H_a$ is (measurable) Hubble's constant at the present moment. This should be correct to the order of $\chi^2$.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You're maybe making things too complicated here, xaxa. See [light-travel distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_measures_(cosmology)#Light-travel_distance) on Wikipedia. It's _"the time (in years) that it took light to reach the observer"_. It isn't a distance at all. Cosmologists eh? By the way, this is a good read: http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808 . See this bit: _can observe galaxies that have, and always have had, recession velocities greater than the speed of light_. Check out the [ant on the rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_on_a_rubber_rope).

Comment: @JohnDuffield probably I am. I'm just confused because it seems that light-travel distance doesn't directly measure neither initial nor current "distance" to the galaxy, so it seems kinda useless.

Comment: That's the thing, xaxa. It isn't a measure of light travel distance. It's a measure of light travel time. IMHO there are other issues in cosmology, it isn't as cut and dried as you might think. But actually, that's a good thing, if you know what I mean. There's scope.

Comment: Well, since light is always travelling at c, light travel distance *is* a distance - it's the distance the light has travelled during the light travel time. It's just not very clear what this actually *means*...